# Origin of the terminology "Completeness" in R

Tags: real-analysis, terminology

When we study Real Analysis first, we usually analyse **R** equipped with the usual metric space. We intuitively make a picture of **R** as a line on which all the points are laid. We say that the set **Q** is not ordered complete. One reason for this is that the set {$x\in $ **Q**: $0\leq x^2 \leq 2$} has no supremum in **Q.** I got stuck in the word "completeness". Why is it so called? I thought that it could be explained in a way as follows:

There is no rational number whose square is 2. By the order completeness property of **R**, we show the existence of a positive real number whose square is 2. We represent it by $\sqrt{2}$. Now if all the rational numbers are plotted on a line, then there is a "hole" at the position of $\sqrt{2}.$ To make the line  "complete", we have to remove the "holes", we have to plot all the real numbers on the line.

I had satisfied myself with this justification. But one day, when I was studying the concept of metric spaces, there I saw the definition of the completeness of metric spaces. It is defined as:

A metric space is said to be complete if all Cauchy sequences in it converge in it.

I again got stuck. But again I justified it, correctly or not. A standard example is given in relation to the completeness of spaces:

Consider a metric space (0, 1) with the usual distance. Then the sequence {$\frac{1}{n}: n \in $**N**} is Cauchy but not convergent. It happens because of "a hole" at the position of $0.$

I want to share this with you guys. But it might be an incomplete motivation for the origin of the word "Completeness" of **R**

Comment: Your intuition is the standard way of understanding completeness, as far as I know. Cauchy sequences are basically sequences that 'want' to converge, and they will if the space they are in is complete. The only thing that can stop a Cauchy sequence from converging is a 'hole' in the space.

Answer (score 3):

It's in the word "complete". This word can mean different things in different circumstances. The general idea is as follows: We have some algebraic or geometric structure $X$. Certain things we'd like to make use of all the time are only partially available in $X$.

*Examples:* In ${\mathbb N}$ we can always add two numbers, but subtraction is not always possible. So ${\mathbb N}$ is "incomplete" with respect to subtraction. In the same way ${\mathbb Z}$ is "incomplete" with respect to division. ${\mathbb Q}$ is incomplete with respect to inverses of strictly monotone functions: ${\rm sq}(x):=x^2$ maps ${\mathbb Q}_{\geq0}$ injectively into ${\mathbb Q}_{\geq0}$, but ${\rm sqrt}:={\rm sq}^{-1}$ is not defined on all of ${\mathbb Q}_{\geq0}$.

In such cases one tries to enlarge the structure $X$ in a "minimal way" to a structure $\tilde X$ which then possesses the desired property without restriction. This process is called a *completion* of $X$ with respect to the property in question.

It so happens that the completion of ${\mathbb Q}$ with respect to the order relation and the completion with respect to the metric $d(x,y):=|x-y|$ result in the same structure ${\mathbb R}$. By the way, there are other "completions" of ${\mathbb Q}$ which are of a completely different nature.

Comment: Following that logic (which, I is the way personally thought of completion of R), why don't we say the reals are incomplete because $ X^2=-1$ has no solutions in them?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD We do, we just use the term "algebraically closed" instead of "complete". It would be confusing to use the same term for the two concepts, since they are not equivalent concepts. It is a little bit confusing that we say "$\mathbb{R}$ is complete" both to mean that it is order complete and to mean that it is metric complete, but they turn out to be equivalent anyway, so it's not so bad.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience the completeness of it can be motivated by how it is constructed in for example Commutative Algebra. Normally using cauchy sequences you can construct from, for example $\mathbb{Q}$ a new ring with new properties, even though the cauchy sequence contains nothing but elements from $\mathbb{Q}$. It becomes quite natural to ask, if we repeat the process is there any new ring we can construct? Or what about the method used to construct $\mathbb{Q}$ itself?

In the instance of real numbers we cannot, we only get a ring that is isomorphic to the real numbers again so they are really the one and the same ring still. It is complete because we cannot do much more to construct new rings from it.

Answer (score 0):

Fréchet's 1906 [thesis](https://books.google.com/books?id=OlFaAAAAYAAJ) speaks of spaces that "admit a generalization of Cauchy's theorem". Hausdorff's 1914 [monograph on set theory](https://archive.org/details/grundzgedermen00hausuoft) calls such a space *[vollständig](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vollst%C3%A4ndig)*, meaning "complete" or "full". (German *voll* is a cognate of English *full*.) Kuratowski's 1930 *[Sur les espaces complets](https://eudml.org/doc/212357)* translates this as *[complet](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/complet#French)*, a French word from which we get the English *complete*, and which in turn derives from Latin verb *[pleō](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pleo)*, "to fill".

Long story short, you're right: we remove the holes by *filling* them in.

Comment: Whose thesis?  Not Cauchy's.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo; fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The definition you saw for completeness in terms of Cauchy sequences is in perfect alignment with your understanding of completeness as including irrational numbers. Consider the sequence 3, 3.1, 3.14, 3.141 3.1415, 3.14159, ... where each additional term adds another digit of $\pi$. This is a Cauchy sequence and it represents the irrational number $\pi$. A similar Cauchy sequence can be formed for each of the irrational numbers.

Comment: Rather: such a sequence *exists*. But most of them are not definable.